# Popup Menu commands in Windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, menu, popup

I have designed an Appbar with an Add button. When user clicks on the add button, a PopupMenu opens and provides two options as given. I wanna bind them two commands. I searched a lot and there are so many different ways. Can someone please tell me how can I do that. I need to show a popup when user clicks on the button.

Language is XAML/C#

```
    private async void AddTaskButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu();
    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Everyday Task"));             
    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Onetime Task"));
    await menu.ShowAsync(new Point(10,680));
    }
```

I wanna add commands to the MenuItem but not able to in windows store apps. Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of doing it but it is not the best (should be used binding) :

When you add the `UICommand` you have to set additional properties, like in the code below. I have taken advantage of your code, and modified a little also on the matter of positioning the `PopUpMenu` at calculated coordinates :) like below :

```
private async void AddTaskButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu();

    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand
                          {
                              Id = 1,
                              Label = "Everyday Task",
                              Invoke = DoTasks 
                          });  
    menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand
                          {
                              Id = 2,
                              Label = "Onetime Task",
                              Invoke = DoTasks 
                          });
    //Determine position of where to show the PopUp :
    var pointTransform = ((Button) sender).TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
    var screenCoords = pointTransform.TransformPoint(new Point(50, 10)); 
    //50, 10 are Horizontal and Vertical offsets, you should customize them as you wish.            

    await menu.ShowAsync(screenCoords);
}
```

Afterwards, you will need the `DoTasks` method :

```
private void DoTasks(IUICommand command)
{
    var currentId = (int) command.Id;

    switch(currentId)
    {
        case 1 :
        {
        //your Everyday Task code here
        }
        case 2 :
        {
        //your OneTime Task code here
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use, different `Invoke` - that would mean, using two different methods.